Intersection of a power set of any set X belonging to a non empty collection C of sets
In trying to do Halmos's "Naive set theory" exercises (found at the very end of the chapter on power sets), I came across the fairly easy to understand proof that
1:
$$\bigcap_{X\in P(E)}X=\varnothing$$
The intersection of the sets belonging to any power set is empty, because the empty set is an element of every power set and there are no elements in the empty set. Hence, there can't be the elements of all sets of a power set. The intersection of X such that X belongs to a power set = {}.
But I also came across the following identity that's been puzzling me:
2:
$$\bigcap_{X\in C}P(X)=P(\bigcap_{X\in C}X)$$
where $X$ is a set, $C$ is a non-empty collection of sets, and $P(X)$ is the power set of $X$. In other words, given a set X belonging to a collection C of sets, the intersection of the power set of X is equal to the power set of the intersection of X.
Here's what I don't understand. I get that the power set of the intersection of any set X belonging to a non-empty collection C of sets can be a fairly "normal" power set, but how can the intersection of a power set (i.e, INTERSECTION of P(X) such that X∈C) be anything other than the empty set, as given in the first identity? The intersection of P(X) should give the members of all the members of P(x), which should be the empty set itself, given that the empty set is a member of P(x).
How is the intersection of the sets belonging to a power set (intersection of X such that X∈P(some set)) different from the intersection of a power set (intersection of P(X))? How come the latter doesn't necessarily result in the empty set?

Your interpretation 'given a set X belonging to a collection C of sets, the intersection of the power set of X' is not correct.
$\bigcap_{X\in C}P(X)$ is not the 'intersection of a powerset' $P(X)$ (i.e. the intersection of all subsets of some 'given' $X$, which would indeed be empty, as proved in your first exercise).
It is the intersection of the powersetS of all $X$s of the collection $C$, so $$Y\in\bigcap_{X\in C}P(X)$$$$\iff\forall X\in C\quad Y\in P(X)$$
$$\iff\forall X\in C\quad Y\subset X$$
$$\iff Y\subset\bigcap_{X\in C}X$$
$$\iff Y\in P(\bigcap_{X\in C}X).$$

That made perfect sense. So if I had a collection C of sets = {{}, {{}}}, the intersection of the powersets of all its sets (P({}) = {{}} and P({{}}) = {{}, {{}}}, which, coincidentally, is also equal to C) would be the set with the empty set ({{}}), because the empty set belongs to both powersets. The general case you gave also makes perfect sense. Much appreciated.
